# Exporting .mtl (with .obj) and multiple textures

Tags: materials, export

I tried search previously on this issue, but only came across issues where people were not having their `.mtl` file generated when exporting a `.obj` file.

I have been able to successfully exporting a `.obj` file with its accompanying `.mtl` file. The files seem to contain all of the relevant information, except for in the .mtl file:

```
newmtl test-material
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 0.000000
illum 2
map_Kd textures/test-01.png
map_d textures/test-01.png
```

In blender, for material `test-material`, I actually have two textures: `test-01.png` and `test-02.png`. Both textures have their boxes checked for active, I see both textures laid on top of one another, yet the exported `.mtl` only shows the first texture.

Is there an option I'm missing? Does `.mtl` not support the case where a material has multiple textures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wavefront doesn't support multiple textures. You can only add one diffuse/specular/normal/... texture per material. To export both, you'll need to bake them together to one texture.

See the specification here: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/